# SQL-AGGREGATE DATA TO GET TOP X

Tags: sql-server

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE
(
    YEAR nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    QUARTER nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    COUNTRY nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    CUSTOMER nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    AMOUNT bigint NOT NULL
)
```

This is the query I would like to run on the above table

```
WITH CTE_1(Y,Q,C,CU,A) AS
(
    SELECT TOP (10) 
        YEAR, QUARTER,
        COUNTRY, CUSTOMER,
        SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMT
    FROM 
        [BikeStores].[dbo].[TESTTABLE]
    WHERE 
        CUSTOMER NOT LIKE 'Others' 
        AND YEAR LIKE '2020' 
        AND QUARTER LIKE 'Q1 2020' 
        AND COUNTRY LIKE 'INDIA'
    GROUP BY 
        YEAR, QUARTER, COUNTRY, CUSTOMER
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    YEAR, QUARTER, COUNTRY, 'Others',
    SUM(T.AMOUNT)
FROM 
    DBO.TESTTABLE AS T
WHERE 
    CUSTOMER NOT IN (SELECT CTE_1.CU FROM CTE_1) 
    AND YEAR LIKE '2020' 
    AND QUARTER LIKE 'Q1 2020' 
    AND COUNTRY LIKE 'INDIA'
GROUP BY
    YEAR, QUARTER, COUNTRY, 'Others';
```

Running this query, I get an error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
>   Column 'DBO.TESTTABLE.YEAR' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

It worked, if I let empty columns after SELECT like below code.

```
UNION ALL
SELECT '','','','Others',SUM(T.AMOUNT)
FROM DBO.TESTTABLE AS T
WHERE CUSTOMER NOT IN (SELECT CTE_1.CU FROM CTE_1) AND YEAR LIKE '2020' AND QUARTER LIKE 'Q1 2020' AND COUNTRY LIKE 'INDIA'
```

I need query to get columns as well not empty.

Comment: @sacse I tried to format but couldn't do it. Can you suggest me how can I format sql query correctly.

Comment: change `TYEAR` to `T.YEAR`   Because `T` is the alias used for `dbo.testtable`

Comment: @AAP there are options available at the top banner of the edit box. Mostly blockquote (CTRL+Q) and code sample(CTRL+K) are required to present the case correctly.

Comment: Side notes: Just using `nvarchar(max)` for everything isn't a good design choice. And that `ORDER BY` in the CTE is useless. The results in the overall query might be in any order unless there's an `ORDER BY` clause for the *outermost* query. Instead of using `LIKE` with no pattern simply `=` would be clearer. You shouldn't combine `*` and an explicit list of columns in a `UNION ALL`. Explicitly define the columns in both queries to make sure you get the right results.

Comment: The error message is quite clear. If you have in your query AGGREGATE functions (like SUM, GROUP BY, etc.), you cannot have any field within the SELECT list that is not included in an AGGREGATE function. The error message even tells you which field is causing the conflict, i.e. `DBO.TESTTABLE.YEAR`. Of course, once you put this field in an aggregate function you will get the same error in the next field (`QUARTER`), and this will go on till your query is __syntactically__ correct (though it might not yield the result you are expecting).

Comment: Any idea to workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to run the query and it runs fine.

```
;WITH CTE_1(Y,Q,C,CU,A) AS
(
    SELECT TOP (10) 
        YEAR, QUARTER,
        COUNTRY, CUSTOMER,
        SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMT
    FROM 
        dbo.[TESTTABLE]
    WHERE 
        CUSTOMER NOT LIKE 'Others' 
        AND YEAR LIKE '2020' 
        AND QUARTER LIKE 'Q1 2020' 
        AND COUNTRY LIKE 'INDIA'
    GROUP BY 
        YEAR, QUARTER, COUNTRY, CUSTOMER
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    YEAR, QUARTER, COUNTRY, 'Others' CUSTOMER,
    SUM(T.AMOUNT)
FROM 
    DBO.TESTTABLE AS T
WHERE 
    CUSTOMER NOT IN (SELECT CTE_1.CU FROM CTE_1) 
    AND YEAR LIKE '2020' 
    AND QUARTER LIKE 'Q1 2020' 
    AND COUNTRY LIKE 'INDIA'
GROUP BY
    YEAR, QUARTER, COUNTRY;
```

Please see the db<>fiddle [**here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=95a38f4f933200c2cd05a8eb5cf6a0d8).

Comment: @AAP Can you please provide some sample data?

Comment: I don't know how to upload sample data file.

Comment: @AAP just put some sample data in the code inside https://dbfiddle.uk/ and provide the link here.

Comment: Please find data (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0fcdf1a1d5c2ad82be12e0534d265ee8).

Comment: @AAP Please check the link in the answer (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=95a38f4f933200c2cd05a8eb5cf6a0d8) if that's what's expected.

Comment: Yes, this is what I expected. Thanks a lot dear. How can I approve your answer? You selected 6 fields instead 5 why? `SELECT 
    YEAR, QUARTER, COUNTRY, 'Others' CUSTOMER,
    SUM(T.AMOUNT)`

Comment: @AAP AHTH! Fields are 5 only, Customer is just an alias for the value 'Others' (if I got that correctly..)